# Issues with For loops and wmic

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic

I'm trying to transfer a file onto a remote computer with a batch file. I don't have permissions to use xcopy or copy. I can't use something like psexec for security reasons. Just echoing with \servername\filelocation won't work either due to permissions. The only way so far I have found is to do a for loop over the file and use a wmic call to echo each line out on the remote computer, but for some reason this isn't working. I get duplicate lines and others don't show up at all (I think this is due to special characters). I thought it might have due to timing so I added a one second wait after each wmic call. It was a slight improvement but still doesn't work. Any other ways to do it or ideas as to why wmic causes duplicates?

Code from the comment:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%H in (Filename) do (
    wmic /user:%user% /password:%pass% /node:%node% process call create "cmd.exe /c echo %%H >> Location"
  ) & (Timeout /T 2
)
```

Comment: If you don't have the permission, it could be forbidden by intentioen

Comment: I'm doing internal testing so if it was done intentionally it was to see if doing this was possible with these restrictions.

Comment: for /F "tokens=*" %%H in (Filename) do (wmic /user:%user% /password:%pass% /node:%node% process call create "cmd.exe /c echo %%H >> Location") & (Timeout /T 2)   I'm looking into using net use to map the drive instead. It might end up being easier if I have permissions.

Comment: What does the contents of `Filename` look like?

Comment: I'm really surprised that you'd have rights to start a process on the remote machine but not be able to write a file to it.

Comment: If you don't have write permissions to the remote computer then how will the `wmic` command work?  Or is that using different credentials?

Comment: This is definitely part of the issue. The program was not running as the expected user. I think I'm likely going to ultimately have to use jeb's type of solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a test I have to revise my assumption, the order seems never be changed.
<strike>As you start one process per line and each process is independent, I assume that they are able to run in any order.</strike>

Many of them will be processed in your expected order, but not all.

The major problem are the special characters and also commas and quotes.
The special characters can be escaped with a simple caret, but a comma seems immune against any escaping.
Also linefeeds seems unescapable.
This seems a side effect of the `wmic process call` syntax.

It can be solved with a helper batch, that can also be created via `wmic`.

```
set "recv=(echo set param=%%*& echo(& echo(& echo setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion& echo set param=!param:\n=^^& echo(& echo(!& echo echo(!param!^>^>c:\temp\new.bat) "
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
wmic /node:%server% process call create "cmd.exe /c !recv!> c:\temp\recv.bat"
endlocal
timeout /t 2
```

This produces a batch file named `recv.bat`

```
set param=%*


setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set param=!param:\n=^

!
echo(!param!>>c:\temp\new.bat
```

Which can accept one parameter and split it into multiple lines.

```
recv.bat Line1\nLine2
```

Comment: It is a small file less than 7500 characters. When you say create one process do you mean literally have the entire file in an echo statement? I didn't follow what you meant by that.

Comment: @TBrenner I suppose your main problem are the special characters and comma

Comment: I think this is pretty much what I need to do to get this working so I'll mark your answer as right. I should be able to figure out any tweaking I need on my own. Thank you for all your help.